# how to reference to a range being a combination of two or more separate ranges in pure Excel

Tags: excel, reference

I want to reference a combination of two ranges that would be treated as one reference in pure Excel function. Specifically, in DGET function I would like to provide Criteria range that would be a combination of two or more ranges: one range with names of columns and the other separate range(s) with criteria. I tried to write DGET(TableRange, "Column_Name", CHOOSE({1,2},A1:B1,A10:B10)) and received an error "A value used in this formula is of a wrong value" probably because I provided an array rather than a reference.

Comment: The criteria of [the DGET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DGET-function-455568bf-4eef-45f7-90f0-ec250d00892e) must be a pure **range**, not a calculated array.

Comment: You can try to use `SUMPRODUCT` or `SUMIFS` to probably get your result.